# PhoneGap Play m3u8 Video

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, cordova, m3u8

I have an `index.html` with an `iframe` and inside that `iframe` I have the following code:

```
<a id="watch-live-btn" href="http://the.location.to/playlist.m3u8" target="_parent"></a>
```

The video plays fine on iOS and when I hit "Done" I'm sent back to the app with no problems. When I try this on Android it just sits there for some time doing nothing. The app is still active in the mean time.

iOS: 6.1
Android 4.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a phonegap  plugin. There is one already created here for playing videos:

https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer

If you want to stream on android pre 3.0 you can modify the  plugin to use the Vitamio library as well:

http://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/

Comment: Hello, how I can modify the plugin to use vitamio, do you have some instructions?

Comment: @dustin .can you show me how to call that video player plugin from javascript?