# Cordova : How read video(m3u8)?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I make a mobile application with Apache Cordova and I want to play a m3u8 video with this code:

```
<video controls="controls" webkit-playsinline >
    <source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="my_video.m3u8"/>
</video>
```

Comment: What error do you get using that code?

Comment: There is no error because this file is here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949510/phonegap-play-m3u8-video

Comment: m3u8 isn't a video format, is a playlist format